# zipping before ddply / mapply on dataframe

Tags: r, plyr

I have a dataframe :

```
> s <- expand.grid(c(T,F),c(T,F))
> s
   Var1  Var2
1  TRUE  TRUE
2 FALSE  TRUE
3  TRUE FALSE
4 FALSE FALSE
```

and would like to duplicate each line a number of times, which is stored in a vector :

```
> r <- c(2,3,4,1)
```

Do you know how to do that?
In functional programming terms, it would just be a mapping over zipped list, duplicate, and collect.

I am not sure on how to do either the zip with **plyr**, or the map with `mapply`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much easier than all that:

```
s[rep(1:4,times = r),]
     Var1  Var2
1    TRUE  TRUE
1.1  TRUE  TRUE
2   FALSE  TRUE
2.1 FALSE  TRUE
2.2 FALSE  TRUE
3    TRUE FALSE
3.1  TRUE FALSE
3.2  TRUE FALSE
3.3  TRUE FALSE
4   FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: oh... you are so multi-dimensionnal, and thought-provocative